# How to achieve a more accurate distance from device to Beacon?

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I am sorry if this has been asked in one way shape or another. I have started working with beacons, and in Xcode (Swift) - using CoreLocation. I really need a more accurate determination between the device and a beacon though. So far I have been using the standard proximity region values (Far, Near, and Immediate), however this just isn't cutting it at all. It seems far too unstable for the solution I am looking for - which is a simple one at best.

My scenario;

I need to display notifications, adverts, images etc to the users device when they are approximately 4 meters away from the beacon. This sounds simple enough, but when I found out that the only real solutions there are for beacons are those aforementioned proximity regions, I started to get worried because I need to only display to devices that are 3-5 meters away, no more.

I am aware of the accuracy property of the CLBeacon class, however Apple state it should not be used for accurate positioning of beacons, which I believe is what I am trying to achieve.

Is there a solution to this? Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Olly

Comment: Have not dealed with Beacons for quite a while, but I remember there is some kind of "power" value the beacon can send, so you can better estimate the signal strength in regards to the sendet signal (power).

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that and update the post accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There are limitations of physics when it comes to estimating distance with Bluetooth radio signals.**  Radio noise, signal reflections, and obstructions all affect the ability to estimate distance based on radio signal strength.  It's OK to use beacons for estimating distance, but **you must set your expectations appropriately.**

Apple's algorithms in CoreLocation take a running average of the measured signal strength over 20 seconds or so, then come up with a distance estimate in meters that is put into the `CLBeacon` accuracy field.  The results of this field are then used to come up with the proximity field.  (0.5 meters or less means immediate, 0.5-3 meters means near, etc.)

When Apple recommends against using the accuracy field, it is simply trying to protect you against unrealistic expectations.   This will never be an exact estimate in meters.  Best results will come with a phone out of a pocket, with no obstructions between the beacon and the phone, and the phone relatively stationary.  **Under best conditions, you might expect to get distance estimates of +/- 1 meter at close distances of 3 meters or less.  The further you get away, the more variation you will see.**

You have to decide if this is good enough for your use case.  If you can control the beacons there are a few things you can do to make the results as good as possible:

1. **Turn the beacon transmitter power setting up as high as possible.**  This gives you a higher signal to noise ratio, hence better distance estimates.
2. **Turn the advertising rate up as high as possible.**  This gives you more statistical samples, hence better distance estimates.
3. **Place your beacons in locations where there will be as few obstructions as possible.**
4. **Always calibrate your beacon** after making the changes like above.  Calibration involves measuring the signal level at 1 meter and storing this as a calibration constant inside the beacon.  Consult your beacon manufacturer instructions for details of how to do this calibration.